# Simple date calculation to show old records

Tags: oracle

How to select from `v$session` records where `logon_time` is less than 2 days before current date?

```
SELECT * FROM v$session WHERE logon_time + 2 <= currentDate (???)
```

Comment: Are you looking for sysdate ?
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm

Comment: Maybe yes. But solved this as logon_time <= '8-JUN-12' and it works (needed only for homework).

Comment: More recent dates are _greater than_ older dates so if you only want logins less than 48 hours and 0 seconds old, it should be `WHERE logon_time + 2 > SYSDATE`.  As for, using '8-JUN-12' it's safer to explicitly convert that string to a date with something like: `TO_CHAR('08-JUN-2012', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`.

Comment: I wanna logon_time older than 2 days.

Comment: And your "homework" will be accepted if you're asked to provide rows where login_time is less than 2 days before the current date, and you hard-code the date? Somehow I doubt it. Also, if you're asked to do this for homework, is it not in your learning materials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE logon_time <= sysdate - 2;
```

Or perhaps:

```
WHERE logon_time <= sysdate - interval '2' DAY;
```